# jquery ajax intercept before success or cancel sucess

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi I want add a common handler before call success.

for example:
Server always send data like {errorCode:1,errorMsg:"blah"}
if errorCode == 1 then in the common handler I should show a messagebox,and cancel the success function.

Edit: 
PS: This is a hand down project, I can't modify the architecture.

Comment: Is it not an option not to yield a 200 response in case of an error? In that case you could register a common error handler, and don't worry about cancelling `success` as it will never be called for non-successful responses?

Comment: [`ajaxError`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxerror/) is the name of the global error listener.

Comment: @DavidHedlund if it's a starter project,i will take your advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a function - called, say, `ajaxSuccess` - that is accessible globally, which wraps an ajax success callback with your additional checks. In this example, it calls `handleError` if the response contains an `errorCode`, otherwise the success callback is called:

```
function ajaxSuccess(callback) {
   return function(response, textStatus, xhr) {
      if(typeof response == 'object' && 'errorCode' in response) {
         handleError(response, xhr);
      } else {
         callback.apply(this, arguments);
      }
   };
}

function handleError(error, xhr) {
   alert('AJAX error ' + error.errorCode + ':\n' + error.errorMsg);
}
```

In this way, you could always make sure your success callbacks are proxied through `ajaxSuccess`:

```
$.post(url, data, ajaxSuccess(function(response) {
   alert(response);
}));
```

I think this gives you a better idea of what's going on as you're reading the code, trying to debug something, but if you really do want to make a global handler, and hide that `ajaxSuccess` call, I suppose you could set a default `beforeSend` listener that does this for you:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if('success' in settings && typeof settings.success == 'function') {
            settings.success = ajaxSuccess(settings.success);
        }
    }
});
```

Note, however, that this would just be setting the *default* `beforeSend`. If you make an AJAX call and decide that you need `beforeSend` for something else, manually setting that would override the default option. So for those scenarios you would need to remember to manually wrapp your success callback in `ajaxSuccess`.

Comment: Thanks,you are genius.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking to something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"http://some-post-url.com"
}).done(function(data)
{
    var parsed = $.parseJSON(data);
    if(parsed["errorCode"] == 1) {
        //error code here
    } else {
        //success code here
    }
})
```

You just have to evaluate that data server response.

Comment: it's not only for one request,but for all requests.